# Looking for a design that contains a distraction object

Tags: education

> *Pliny the Elder* tells in his *[Natural History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_History_(Pliny))*, that the painters *Zeuxis* and *Parrasio* -the fifth century BC- discussed which of the two painted with the most realism. To prove it, each one proposed a work. That of *Zeuxis* was a boy with a basket of grapes; some birds and flies, confused, approached to peck them and all assumed that *Zeuxis* won.
>
> But then *Parrasio* said:
>
> -In agreement; now, remove the canvas that covers my work.
>
> And when *Zeuxis* wanted to do it, he could not, because the cloth was painted and as he had believed it to be real, he considered himself defeated by the perfection of his opponent.

This text extracted (and I hope well translated) from [here](http://atenas-diariodeabordo.blogspot.com/2018/06/moscas-en-la-pintura-muscae-depictae.html), describes a recurrent pictorial element in the old painting and one resulting: the **Trompe-l'œil** and the **Muscae Depictae** respectively. Both have appeared and continue appearing on several occasions in painting.

### Trompe-l'œil

> (French for "deceive the eye", pronounced [tʁɔp lœj]) is an art technique that uses realistic imagery to create the optical illusion that the depicted objects exist in three dimensions. Forced perspective is a comparable illusion in architecture. [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trompe-l%27%C5%93il)

[image]

*Escaping Criticism by Pere Borrell del Caso, 1874*

It is very easy to find *Trompe-l'œil* examples that correspond in Graphic Design, only seeing some figure-ground effect or what is usually called **double reading** in graphics and **double exposure** in images, or simply the design of an element made with another of different typology.

[image: U&Lc]

*U&Lc Magazin*

### Muscae Depictae

> When *Giotto* was still beginning to learn (painting) with *Cimabue*, one day he painted a fly on the nose of a portrait created by the teacher; a fly so natural, that when *Cimabue* returned to continue his work, several times he tried to frighten it with his hand, thinking it was real, until he noticed his mistake.

Whether as a joke or an effect, the fly appears several times in painting as an object of distraction, decoration or signature.

[image: Christus]

*Petrus Christus, Portrait of a Carthusian, 1446*

[image: fly]

[image]

---

Knowing that it exists in painting, there are also personalized elements that are unrelated to those represented in sculpture, architecture and certainly in product design. But, it was impossible for me to find any simple *Muscae Depictae* example among so many graphic design products: corporate image, packaging, web design, publishing, posters ....

A long time ago, while working for a gaming company, after the release of a product to the market, I told the boss that I had put my name - very small - in a corner of one of the screens. Of course it was a joke, but he didn't think so and I had to listen an hour of *business moral lessons*. This was my own failed *Muscae Depictae*.

I would like to have at least one example of *Muscae Depictae* in Graphic Design. Does anyone know any? I could define it as an object that having no any relation with the design appears in some part of it.

---

I add a simple quiz, [this link](https://www.viajablog.com/visitas-teatrales-en-las-ruinas-de-empuries-al-atardecer/) has a picture of an entrance to the Roman ruins of Empúries, Costa Brava. Where's the *Muscae Depictae*?

<sub>I didn't find the right tags for this question</sub>

Comment: I would say that the now common "easter eggs" on the movies are examples of it. Probably some movie posters have it.

Comment: @Rafael I just know the "easter eggs" of Illustrator (the eyes following the mouse), QuarkXpress (the killer robot) and Indesign (the fancy strokes).

Comment: A very long question but not much content to it. I think it'd be better edited down to just the important parts.

Comment: Not sure if this answers it, but.. I've seen an apple on the back of electronic stuff, phones, tablets, always looked like Muscae Depictae to me. Lots of people seem to appreciate it, but I could never figure out why :)

Comment: Wait, what? who thinks about these things? :)

Comment: I'm reminded of the Yorkshire furniture make Robert (Mouseman) Thompson, who carved a little mouse on nearly all his pieces of furniture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Thompson_(designer)

Comment: @Billy Kerr very interesting, I didn't know him.

Comment: Extending trompe l'oeil to figure-ground or general illusions is stretching the concept beyond its meaning. Your definition is also missing a key component: 1:1 scale.

Comment: @Yorik You're right, it's figurative. Anyway, after the extensive explanation described in the question, there are quite erroneous answers. None of the logos showed as examples answers the original question, some not even as Trompe l'oeil. I think that summarizing the whole answer in just an "ok, is an easter-egg", is not even wanting to think what is described in the question and write the first occurrence.

Comment: trompe l'oeil has a very narrow definition. Your question relies heavily on it, but you say that it is easy to find examples in graphic design (it is not) and provide a sample of a horse built from type. This is about as far from trompe l'oeil as you can get. I feel like your question is asking about something else. Tromp l'oeil is lacking in graphic design because it requires a context where one does not expect the illusion. In the 70's, people used to make xerox copies of coins, carefully cut them out and place them in random places. This works fabulously. Not so in a magazine.

Comment: This may be why the answers are not what you'd hoped for. Note also that the fly is not the distraction. The paintings is.

Comment: You should add your own answer whit all this explanation and some examples.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps it is rare in graphic design because graphic design itself is often a distraction, and it would be considered counterproductive to build a distraction into the distraction. However, the most common recurring instance of this that I can think of would be the Droste effect, where the entire image is contained and repeated within itself. This effect often has nothing to do with the message of the advertisement itself, but is there simply as an amusing distraction.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this counts, but there's a perfume bottle "Message d'Amour des Dauphins" with a picture by [Sandro Del-Prete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandro_del_Prete). It depicts a love scene, but if you look at it differently, it displays 9 dolphins (hence the perfume's name). [Here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6016/26375) is a related question on our sister site Skeptics Stack Exchange.

The picture itself is slightly NSFW, so I put it behind a spoiler:

> [image]

Comment: Nice, a clear  Trompe-l'œil  example.

Answer (score 0):

In English these are called *"easter eggs"* (because an Easter holiday tradition is to find eggs that are hidden).

They are found [in graphic](https://indesignsecrets.com/tip-of-the-week-friendly-alien-easter-egg.php) [design software](https://www.highlander.co.uk/blog/hidden-adobe-easter-eggs), [car design](http://www.thejournal.ie/hidden-easter-eggs-in-cars-3923868-Mar2018/), [logos](https://mashable.com/2014/10/25/logos-with-hidden-messages/#pmv.NO24nmqL), [websites](https://www.impactbnd.com/blog/best-internet-easter-eggs-and-marketing-benefits), and many other things.